# Is it possible to access Kernel Parameters from PowerShell in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell

So I'm following along with a certain lecture series (will link at the bottom) and the lecturer who is in Linux is explaining BASH and Shells etc. He is explaining the `sudo` command and as an example, sets the LED brightness of his scroll lock key in his kernel parameters (sys.fs) from 0 to 1 to turn the LED of his scroll lock key on. I am not on Linux however, I am on Windows 10. All I have is PowerShell. Is there a way to edit kernel parameters in Windows 10 while the system is running? And if not, why?

For anyone interested, this is the course: https://missing.csail.mit.edu/

Comment: I think you are looking for `Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI` and its parameters. For example, you can change the brightness of a computer with `(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,x)` where `x` is the brightness you want from 1 to 100

Comment: No, Windows NT is fundamentally different in it's design. The lecture series you're following seems to be tuned around linux (or at least unix-like) operating systems, so either install a linux VM or WSL on your machine before you begin

Comment: "No, Windows NT is fundamentally different in it's design."

Interesting, I thought Windows 10 was using a Linux kernel
Edit: I realize its not that simple though, and will get a VM now. Also, reading up about WMI Objects. Thanks!

Comment: If you have WSL installed, perhaps you can run your command in powershell like `bash -c "sudo <command>"`

Comment: `man bash` returned nothing so my guess is WSL is not installed, moreover I did not even know WSL was a thing and that I could install Linux as a subsystem! This is great stuff, thank you again! I'll research the topic more.

Comment: @NekoMusume Hi, while I have you here could I ask a follow-up question. If I install WSL and get a Linux distro, do you think I could hypothetically follow along with the lecture exercises and skip using a VM altogether? This laptop isnt very high-end and I'm not sure how its going to handle VMware. Thanks again.

Comment: I think so... I haven't tried to see whether WSL could control the Windows Kernel like it could with the Linux Kernel but if it can, it probably is possible. I would suggest installing Windows Terminal from the Windows Store or Ubuntu since they have the Bash (Ubuntu specifically) terminal in them. This will make it easier to follow along as well if it works since you don't have to type `bash -c` each time you are running a command.

Comment: Having VMware just to use the terminal seems kinda over the top imo, when you only need bash terminal, why download the whole OS?

Comment: Roger that, downloading Ubuntu as we speak. I'm eventually going to have to become very intimate with Linux, but thank you for helping me delay the inevitable lol :D I agree, VMware for a few video lectures didnt appeal to me either. If you'd like you can post an answer and I'll mark it as the answer for internet points hehe

Comment: I would suggest that if you install WSL, or preferably WSL2, (depending upon the version of [tag:Windows-10]), that you do not just go for Ubuntu, there are several other alternatives to consider. I would additionally suggest that if you were to use it, you install it before you consider whether Windows Terminal is for you. Finally, if you do install it, do not use the command `bash` as previously advised, the command is `wsl`.